# using a self-signed certificate with Amazon SES

Tags: iis, smtp, iis-8, amazon-ses

I'm configuring **Amazon Simple Email Service**, I get to the point when I try to send an email and I get the error message:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: Authentication required

So I'd like to use a self-signed certificate using IIS 8, but so far I've implemented it and I'm still getting the same error.

- I'm using .net web.config to set the credentials, hostname, and port.

> ```
> <mailSettings>
>       <smtp from="emal@email.com" deliveryMethod="Network" >
>         <network
>           host="my-amazon-host.com"
>           port="25"
>           defaultCredentials="false"
>           enableSsl="true"
>           userName="my-user-name"
>           password="my-password" />
>       </smtp>
> </mailSettings>
> ```

- is there any way to use the self-signed certificate (created by the IIS) and amazon-ses service?
- how to set up that certificate?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=302112&#302112):

> The .NET email TLS libraries only support STARTTLS which SES does not
>   support today. We support what is called "TLS Wrapper" or SMTPS
>   authentication. I can understand how this would be frustrating, but
>   you can use OpenSSL as a workaround and tunnel through that software
>   running on your computer to use .NET to program against our SMTP
>   endpoint.

so I decided to make a custom smtp implementation using amazon [SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-net.html):

```
        var smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");
        var toAddresses = email.To.Select(mailAddress => mailAddress.Address).ToList();
        var destination = new Destination {ToAddresses = toAddresses};
        var subject = new Content(email.Subject);
        var textBody = new Content(email.Body);
        var body = new Body(textBody);
        var message = new Message(subject,body);
        var request = new SendEmailRequest(smtpSection.From, destination, message);
        Amazon.RegionEndpoint region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
        var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(region);

        try
        {
            client.SendEmail(request);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: logger.
            throw;
        }
        finally 
        {
            email.Dispose();
            client.Dispose();
        }
```

and also you need to setup a policy to you user in Iam with the following permissions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "---------",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ses:SendEmail",
        "ses:SendRawEmail"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and remember to add the amazon settings in the app or web config:

```
  <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="-----------------"/>
  <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="-----------------"/>
```

I hope that helps anybody else.
thanks!